# Is it possible to store HashMap to MongoDB / ArangoDB, where HashMap's KEY is custom Java Object and VALUE also custom Java Object

Tags: hashmap, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, arangodb

Is it possible to store HashMap to MongoDB / ArangoDB, where HashMap's KEY is custom Java Object and VALUE also custom Java Object.

```
`Class Customer {
    private String customerName;
    private String customerAddress;
    private HashMap<ContactPerson, Address> customerConacts;    
}`

`class ContactPerson {
    private String name;
    private String mailId;
}`

`class Address {
    private String houseNo;
    private String street;
}`
```

Here, I want to store Customer object to MongoDB / ArangoDB and using Spring data. Is it possible to store Customer Objects into DB?.

Answer (score 1):

Its technically possible yet unusual. System will try to serialize key object into string as json key must be string. At least Spring Data MongoDB is working this way. But e.g. Morphia is raising an issue saying:

> Maps must be keyed by a simple type
>   (Map); interface java.util.Map is
>   not supported as a map key type when key is Map.

So its definitely not recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

In ArangoDB, object keys/attribute names must be strings.
So the only way to use a custom object as the key is to serialize the object into a string first, e.g. by applying something like `JSON.stringify()` to the object. However, that will only be a viable solution if all object members can be serialized to JSON and the resulting serialized string is relatively small. Huge keys will definitely have performance impacts, so I agree to the response from @David Marko that it is not recommended to do this.